# Component Registration Exception with windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I am trying to register a new component in my mvc application using windsor..

First, I referenced to all windsors dlls..

Then I used this code:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    WindsorContainer container;

    public WindsorControllerFactory()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));

        //Registers all components as transient.
        var controllerTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                              where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                              select t;

        foreach(Type t in controllerTypes)
        {
            container.AddComponentLifeStyle(t.FullName, t, LifestyleType.Transient);//Exception thrown here
        }
    }

    protected  virtual IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
    {
        return (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Exception:

> [ComponentRegistrationException: Component SportsStore.Controllers.ProductController could not be registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.]
>      Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Naming.DefaultNamingSubSystem.Register(IHandler handler) in c:\BuildAgent\work\9834359f44c23fee\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\SubSystems\Naming\DefaultNamingSubSystem.cs:237
>      Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.RegisterHandler(String name, IHandler handler, Boolean skipRegistration) in c:\BuildAgent\work\9834359f44c23fee\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:720
>      Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.RegisterHandler(String name, IHandler handler) in c:\BuildAgent\work\9834359f44c23fee\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:713
>      Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddComponent(String key, Type serviceType, Type classType, LifestyleType lifestyle, Boolean overwriteLifestyle) in c:\BuildAgent\work\9834359f44c23fee\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel_ObsoleteAPI.cs:106
>      Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddComponent(String key, Type classType, LifestyleType lifestyle, Boolean overwriteLifestyle) in c:\BuildAgent\work\9834359f44c23fee\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel_ObsoleteAPI.cs:59
>      Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.AddComponentLifeStyle(String key, Type classType, LifestyleType lifestyle) in c:\BuildAgent\work\9834359f44c23fee\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer_ObsoleteAPI.cs:94
>      WindsorControllerFactory..ctor() in D:\Call.of.Duty.Modern.Warfare.3-RELOADED\SportsStore\SportsStore\SportsStore\WindsorControllerFactory.cs:33
>      SportsStore.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in D:\Call.of.Duty.Modern.Warfare.3-RELOADED\SportsStore\SportsStore\SportsStore\Global.asax.cs:31

I modified the web.config as such:

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="castle"
    type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,
Castle.Windsor" />
    <!-- ... leave all the other section nodes as before ... -->
  </configSections>


  <castle>
    <components>
    </components>
  </castle>
```

and in the global asax file, I added this line:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
        new WindsorControllerFactory());
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

The container/windsorContainer is empty as you can see from the web.config file, it has empty component..and I have only one controller to add--- Called ProductController..so how come it adds the controller twice?!!?

Comment: What is the content of the `controllerTypes` collection if you look at it in the debugger?

Comment: it has one controller... and as it enters the loop , it throws an exception saying that that controller was already added

Comment: Whats the reason behind the windsor.. is that functionality is all about serving controllers with different interfaces/types so there behaviors will be able to be changed if i wanted to?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Register instead

```
container.Register
(
    AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()//Identify assembly containing your controllers
        .BasedOn<IController>()
        .If(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<Controllers.HomeController>())
        .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
        .Configure((c => c.LifeStyle.Transient))
);
```